# Reflow is not good in tagged pdf, I don't know the reason?

Tags: pdf, accessibility, reflow

I have a [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J5jr486I8Rwj0dX8zbFftcErsh6jrnHC/view?usp=sharing)I tagged it. And able to read it. But When I press reflow in adobe(View-> Zoom-> Reflow (ctrl+F4)) it's not showing correctly. Some text is missing or graphics messing up.

But I changed one image bbox using "[Axes pdf quick fix](https://www.axes4.com/en/software-services/axespdf)". After that automatically all page reflow is working. Here the [files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KWMFJT_OwlLnNGa3PO0iEX2WVpk9lITL/view?usp=sharing) it is.

What am I missing while tagging. Why it is able to reflow properly after single bbox update in "Axes Pdf".

I want to know the reason why it's not working. And need to fix it. Help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

[Tagging](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/creating-accessible-pdfs.html) a PDF file is about adding metadata so that assistive technology, such as a screen reader, can accurately read the contents of the file.

The Reflow (Ctr+4) option modifies (temporarily) the document so that you can zoomin/magnify and the text reflows to fit the width of your viewport.  See https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/reading-pdfs-reflow-accessibility-features.html#reflow_a_pdf

The two features, tagged PDF and reflow, should not be related, but the Adobe site interestingly says:

> Acrobat temporarily tags an untagged document before reflowing it.

Which I assume means if the document already has tags, then they aren't modified, which could be in invalid assumption.

I compared both documents in the OP, the original one that does not reflow properly and the one modified by [axes4](https://www.axes4.com/en/try-out) that does reflow, the latter of which allows the subtraction examples to display such as:

[image]

Saying the original does not reflow properly isn't quite accurate. It actually does reflow the text to fit within the viewing width.  It's just the subtraction example, which is a <Figure> in the tag, does not display.

I tried looking at the properties of the <Figure> tag to see what was different but could not find anything obvious that would allow it to display in the modified file. I looked specifically at the bbox attribute in the "Edit Attribute Objects..." dialog and the bbox is different between the two files but I don't see how that affects the reflow.

[image]

**Side note**: The alt text for the first figure says:

> *"First Line: 3816. Second Line: 88,846. Third Line: negative 74,898. Fourth Line: hline 8."*

[image]

The "3816" isn't quite right because it has an extra '8' in it. In fact, the '3' and the '16' should be separated by a space because they're two numbers and not '316'.  The alt text doesn't really convey what's in the figure because you don't get a sense that the '16' is because you borrowed a 10 from the column to the left and that the '4' in '88846' was changed to a '3' because you took 10 from it.

I'm also not sure what "hline 8" means. Perhaps "horizontal line"?

Anyway, this is a lot of information for not answering the question but since I spent time researching it, I at least wanted to post what I had found.

Comment: " I looked specifically at the bbox attribute in the "Edit Attribute Objects..." dialog and the bbox is different between the two files but I don't see how that affects the reflow."
This bbox difference doesn't matter, even non working bbox values you can give in axes pdf and it's still working.